# Why write while(!false) instead of simply writing while(true)?

Tags: operating-system, locking, critical-section, mutual-exclusion

I'm a web developer and often times I come across situations where I can answer this question myself.

I'm preparing for an exam and learning about **Lock Variables** used as solution for Synchronization Mechanisms in **Operating Systems**

This is the code given -

```
//0 - free
//1 - occupied 

//ENTRY SECTION
initialize lock = 0;
while(lock != 0); //infinite loop to stop another process from entering critical section
lock = 1;
----
----
----

//EXIT SECTION
lock = 0;
```

My question is, why is it simply not `while(lock == 1)` instead of `while(lock != 0)`? I've tried solving problems manually and I haven't found any errors while using `while(lock == 1)`

Can someone give me an example where using `while(lock == 1)` will fail?